# Huge amount of debug data with AWS for Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I am using the was-sdk-java.
Recently I get huge amount of debug data, a snapshot below, and it completely bugs down my system (as each line item is longer). Even the binary data appears.

```
2015-03-01 17:10:44,644 DEBUG ~ CookieSpec selected: best-match
2015-03-01 17:10:44,644 DEBUG ~ Auth cache not set in the context
2015-03-01 17:10:44,644 DEBUG ~ Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2015-03-01 17:10:44,644 DEBUG ~ Sending request: GET /app1/xxx HTTP/1.1
2015-03-01 17:10:44,644 DEBUG ~  >> "GET /app1/xxx HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
2015-03-01 17:10:44,645 DEBUG ~  >> "Host: testcerts.xxx.eu[\r][\n]"
2015-03-01 17:10:44,645 DEBUG ~  >> "Authorization: AWS xxx:xxx[\r][\n]"
2015-03-01 17:10:44,645 DEBUG ~  >> "Date: Sun, 01 Mar 2015 17:10:44 GMT[\r][\n]"
2015-03-01 17:10:44,645 DEBUG ~  >> "User-Agent: aws-sdk-java/1.7.13 Linux/3.13.0-46-generic OpenJDK_64-Bit_Server_VM/24.75-b04/1.7.0_75[\r][\n]"
2015-03-01 17:10:44,645 DEBUG ~  >> "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
2015-03-01 17:10:44,645 DEBUG ~  >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
2015-03-01 17:10:44,645 DEBUG ~  >> "[\r][\n]"
2015-03-01 17:10:44,646 DEBUG ~ >> GET /app1/xxx HTTP/1.1
2015-03-01 17:10:44,646 DEBUG ~ >> Host: testcerts.xxx
2015-03-01 17:10:44,646 DEBUG ~ >> Authorization: AWS xxx:xxx
2015-03-01 17:10:44,646 DEBUG ~ >> Date: Sun, 01 Mar 2015 17:10:44 GMT
2015-03-01 17:10:44,646 DEBUG ~ >> User-Agent: aws-sdk-java/1.7.13 Linux/3.13.0-46-generic OpenJDK_64-Bit_Server_VM/24.75-b04/1.7.0_75
2015-03-01 17:10:44,646 DEBUG ~ >> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
2015-03-01 17:10:44,646 DEBUG ~ >> Connection: Keep-Alive
2015-03-01 17:10:44,655 DEBUG ~  << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
2015-03-01 17:10:44,656 DEBUG ~  << "Server: nginx[\r][\n]"
2015-03-01 17:10:44,656 DEBUG ~  << "Date: Sun, 01 Mar 2015 17:10:44 GMT[\r][\n]"
2015-03-01 17:10:44,656 DEBUG ~  << "Content-Type: application/x-pkcs12[\r][\n]"
2015-03-01 17:10:44,656 DEBUG ~  << "Content-Length: 3249[\r][\n]"
2015-03-01 17:10:44,656 DEBUG ~  << "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
2015-03-01 17:10:44,656 DEBUG ~  << "Bucket: "testcerts"[\r][\n]"
2015-03-01 17:10:44,657 DEBUG ~  << "Accept-Ranges: bytes[\r][\n]"
2015-03-01 17:10:44,657 DEBUG ~  << "Last-Modified: Fri, 23 Jan 2015 10:04:12 GMT[\r][\n]"
2015-03-01 17:10:44,657 DEBUG ~  << "ETag: "xxx"[\r][\n]"
2015-03-01 17:10:44,657 DEBUG ~  << "Age: 0[\r][\n]"
2015-03-01 17:10:44,658 DEBUG ~  << "X-Cache-Hit: No[\r][\n]"
2015-03-01 17:10:44,658 DEBUG ~  << "Accept-Ranges: bytes[\r][\n]"
2015-03-01 17:10:44,658 DEBUG ~  << "[\r][\n]"
2015-03-01 17:10:44,658 DEBUG ~ Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
2015-03-01 17:10:44,658 DEBUG ~ << HTTP/1.1 200 OK
2015-03-01 17:10:44,659 DEBUG ~ << Server: nginx
2015-03-01 17:10:44,659 DEBUG ~ << Date: Sun, 01 Mar 2015 17:10:44 GMT
2015-03-01 17:10:44,659 DEBUG ~ << Content-Type: application/x-pkcs12
2015-03-01 17:10:44,659 DEBUG ~ << Content-Length: 3249
2015-03-01 17:10:44,659 DEBUG ~ << Connection: keep-alive
2015-03-01 17:10:44,659 DEBUG ~ << Bucket: "testcerts"
2015-03-01 17:10:44,660 DEBUG ~ << Accept-Ranges: bytes
2015-03-01 17:10:44,660 DEBUG ~ << Last-Modified: Fri, 23 Jan 2015 10:04:12 GMT
2015-03-01 17:10:44,660 DEBUG ~ << ETag: "xxx"
2015-03-01 17:10:44,660 DEBUG ~ << Age: 0
2015-03-01 17:10:44,660 DEBUG ~ << X-Cache-Hit: No
2015-03-01 17:10:44,660 DEBUG ~ << Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

I tried to turn this off in log4j, as debugging of the whole application is now impossible:

```
log4j.logger.httpclient.wire=INFO
log4j.logger.com.amazonaws=WARN
log4j.logger.com.amazonaws.request=WARN
```

But this doesn't seem to make any difference. Any suggestion why I suddenly get all these log warning, and what I can do about it?

Comment: Do you know what class or package these logs are coming from?

Comment: No, it doesn't give me more details then what I posted. But it is AWS, I know that much.